# How to get the top row in C# of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I just need the top row, the stored procedure uses TOP 1, but I would like to have it in the C# to future proof this app a little.

```
        protected void Load()
        {
            using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]))
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", objConn))
            {
                objConn.Open();
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                        txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                        txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just call Read() once rather than in a loop.

Comment: Change your while to an if. if (dr.Read())

Comment: What do you mean by _future proof_?  Why send all data over the network when only the 1st record is needed?

Comment: Just in case for when some one else at my company needs to use the historical data for another application and help minimize the amount of stored procedures, also my boss told me this is how he wants it done lol

Comment: Default param as well maybe to future future proof @JustFirstRow BIT = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the loop `while(dr.Read())`:

```
    protected void Load()
    {
        using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connection"]))
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", objConn))
        {
            objConn.Open();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(dr.HasRows && dr.Read()) // <----- This is the change
                {
                    txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                    txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                    txtLabel.Text = dr["label"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```